# Ошибка Bitmap image is not valid на вставку изображения

Tags: delphi, firebird

При попытке вставки изображений в БД, методом:

```
ibdsImage.Insert;
TBlobField(ibdsImage.FieldByName('IMAGE')).LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
ibdsImage.Post;
ibtrMain.CommitRetaining;
```

на второй строке, ошибка (за исключением файлов с расширением "bmp"):

> «exception class EInvalidGraphic with message 'Bitmap image is not valid'.»

Хотя, эти же изображения у меня загружаются и отображаются на convas формы, и компоненте «Image».
Библиотеки «GraphicEx», «jpeg» давно подключены.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Что написано в справке на метод `LoadFromFile` класса `TBlobField`?

Comment: Спасибо, но ошибка ушла. Правда я в коде умышлено ничего не менял. Я так и не понял почему